# Docker file fail to cd into a directory

Tags: curl, docker

Using this [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/popestepheng/meteor-production-docker-example/blob/master/Dockerfile) , line 21 gives the error:

> /bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /home/meteorapp/meteorapp/app

Any idea how to go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't create the app directory.  You've created /home/meteorapp/meteorapp only.  If you create /home/meteorapp/meteorapp/app you'll be set.

If you change your current line 5

> 5. RUN mkdir /home/meteorapp

To look like this:

> 5. RUN mkdir -p /home/meteorapp/meteorapp/app

Then you can/should remove line 9:

> ADD . ./meteorapp

Because the NEW line 5 would have already created all of the meteorapp directories you need, you don't need the ADD statement in line 9. The problem you saw will be resolved.

No guarantee the docker file still has no bugs, but it means it will no longer fail on line 21.

Comment: Please indicate the problem line in the Dockerfile and what it should be in order to fix the problem.

Comment: I updated the response above